# How to access angular $http response custom headers?

Tags: ajax, angularjs

Here is my code:

```
$http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: myURL,
         headers: {
           //BLAH
         },
         data: {
           // BLAH BLAH
         }
     }).success(function(data, status, headers) {
         deferred.resolve({
         // This is not possible:
         sessionId: headers('sessionId')
        });
   });
```

I would like to access sessionId attribute from headers, but only header I seem to find is Content-Type.

What may be the cause why this does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this post useful: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/128

It states the following:

> After research I found the solution: you have to tell your api server to "expose" the custom headers. You can do this by using the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header. The value is the headers you want to be able to access. So it'd look like: `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Your-Header, Another-Header`.

Adding this extra header solved my problem.

Comment: Another visible layer without this setting is according to the source  `Cache-Control`.